# Element type error in Query component only when using a HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo-client, higher-order-components

I've created a `withInfiniteScroll` higher order component for adding infinite scrolling to a simple list of data. I'm attempting to use that HOC inside of apollo's `Query` component. This is where I get an element error:

> Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from
>   the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named
>   imports.
>
> Check the render method of `Query`.

I also see this error (not sure what that means...):

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: ObservableQuery with this id doesn't
>   exist: 3

The code works fine when I'm not using the HOC

```
<Query>
    {(data) => return <List list={data.list} /> }
</Query>
```

But it breaks when I add the HOC...

```
import withInfiniteScroll from './withInfiniteScroll';

const ListWithInfiniteScroll = withInfiniteScroll(List);

<Query>
    {(data) => return <ListWithInfiniteScroll list={data.list} /> }
</Query>
```

I'm fairly sure that I'm not mixing up default/named imports. For reference, here is the HOC implementation (simplified):

```
const withInfiniteScroll = (Component) => {
    class WithInfiniteScroll extends React.Component {
        // Stuff here

        render() {
            return <Component {...this.props} />;
        }
    }
}

export default withInfiniteScroll;
```

Comment: Is your syntax alright? Your example shows `<Query> return ... </Query>` But that should be `<Query>{(data) => <ListWithInfiniteScroll /></Query>`

Comment: @Niekert yeah, sorry. was trying to be brief and accidentally left it out. edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you do not seem to return the new `class` created in your higher order component function. Because of that, `withInfiniteScroll(Component)` will return undefined. Resulting in the `Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.`

Try this:

```
const withInfiniteScroll = (Component) => {
    class WithInfiniteScroll extends React.Component {
        // Stuff here

        render() {
            return <Component {...this.props} />;
        }
    }

    // This line is important!
    return WithInfiniteScroll;
}

export default withInfiniteScroll;
```

You could also remove the brackets around the fat arrow function to directly return the class, like so:

```
const withInfiniteScroll = Component => class extends React.Component { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that! That fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass data to the list and wrap into HOC after, something like

```js
import withInfiniteScroll from './withInfiniteScroll';

const ListWithData = (props) => (
  <Query>
    {(data) => return <List list={data.list} /> }
  </Query>
)

const ListWithInfiniteScroll = withInfiniteScroll(ListWithData);
```